# What's the meaning of the word "languid" in the following context?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, adjectives

"His conversation seemed to excite a general though languid interest"

One of the definitions in TFD is:
b. Slow-moving or weak in force: languid breezes.

Can it mean the interestest was weak in force?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The passage is a translation of Dostoevsky. The original word, ленивое, is commonly translated to "lazy."

The idea is that Marmeladov describes situations that you might normally be alarmed about, but his manner makes it clear that nothing important is actually happening. He's drunk, right? Is it real? Is it fiction? In a later sentence, the narrator says this of him: "This habit develops into a necessity in some drunkards."

The listeners are interested for a moment—but not enough to take action. Some of them actually laugh at the speaker's foolishness.

I think people feel this way when they watch TV. You say, "Oh, it's terrible that people sell girls into slavery. Do we have any more potato crisps?"